# Concern about attitude "Shoot and run", gamification, loss of Stack Overflow spirit and "it is a lazy man" vote

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today I responded to a question to one person that was clearly beginner on the topic. He asked a simple question and asked for an explanation.

I think that it is really good and Stack Overflow is a really good place to learn in community.

My concern is about that thanks to the gamification of Stack Overflow people try to respond as fast as they can to win scores, but I can see that this is bad for the quality of the content.

This is not about a duplicate question or other things that easily can be detected automatically by the system. This is more about attitude of people. My feeling is that there are people that don't respond because they want to help, but they want to win easy points.

For example, in my case, the response was really simple so I was responding with few comments about errors and wrong practices. Nothing special.

At the same time, another person responded with a quick piece of code and practically no comments. Attitude: "Shoot and run".

So my response was few minutes after the other one, but the person who asked accepted mine because I expend more time trying to help.

But my concerns started with the comment of the other person with the "shoot & run" attitude, that he blamed me for copying his response, but he did not do anything to help more than the necessary to win the point assigned for a selected answer.

So this is the question: How do we avoid this type of people that are decreasing the quality and I think the spirit of Stack Overflow?
I think that in the last few years the number of people with this attitude is growing.

Also, I think that people are using downvotes to punish other people with different opinions in subjective questions, a lot of time with an explanation of why the downvote.

I think that is not an easy way to detect this. Maybe a way to vote, not a negative, but maybe anything like "it is a lazy man" response/question.

Comment: `I think that people are using down votes to punish other people with different opinions in subjective questions` This is (partly) why primarily subjective questions are off topic here.

Comment: `I think that in the last few years the number of people with this attitude is growing.` People have been complaining about this constantly for years and years and years.  Pretty much since the start of the site.  This seems to be largely a recency illusion.  Not to say that it's not a problem, it's just not a *new* problem.

Comment: Why shouldn't I down vote *"it is a lazy man" response/question*?

Comment: @rene No downvote because the response is technically ok. The problem is that it is clear the intention to "no help", only "win"

Comment: I do down vote posts that are technically OK but have little to no value to future visitors. If there is *no help* in the post the answer is not useful so a down vote is legit.

Comment: Search for "fastest gun in the west"

Comment: see also: [Stack Overflow technology makes me write bad answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171172/stack-overflow-technology-makes-me-write-bad-answers)

Comment: The intention of an answerer (to help or to gain points) is completely irrelevant, and judging that is hugely subjective. How are you to know what the answerer is thinking, or what their intentions are unless they tell you? If the answer is correct, it's correct, regardless of the intention.

Comment: @TinyGiant Because the person is explicitly asking for help to learn, and a copy&paste is technically valid, but no helping like the person need.

Comment: @TinyGiant "If the answer is *useful*, it's *useful*, regardless of the intention." correctness is of course only one component of a quality/useful answer.

Comment: @Servy yeah, that one.

Comment: @angelcervera That means nothing at all. Stack Overflow is all about copy and pastable examples. If an example can not not be run by simply copying and pasting, it isn't a good example. Some explanation is always a good thing, but it isn't required. Some people are really good at programming, but not so good at explaining things or even the english language. Don't waste your time and everyone elses trying to subjectively determine the intention of the author (with regards to help vs rep), just worry about whether or not the answer is useful in and of itself.

Comment: What this all boils down is simple: *users want fast answers*. Given that users here type faster than average, we will go with 60 words per minute, 300 characters per minute. This means that an answer posted in the free-edit time window (5 minutes) is limited to 1500 characters of *new content* (as in there is no copy paste); however, copy paste takes some time so this number will be decreased based on the amount or frequency of copy paste. Your answer contained 1290 characters, of which roughly 225 were copy pasted.

Comment: It took you roughly 19 minutes to compose this answer though, which means your new content was produced at a rate of 56 characters per minute, or roughly 10 words per minute. Conversely, the competing answer took 12 minutes, totaling 612 characters, of which roughly 175 were copy pasted. This means their new content was produced at a rate of 36 characters per minute, or roughly 6 words per minute. These rates are rough estimates. However, the point I am getting at here is that while you may have been producing twice the content, it took you longer.

Comment: In the future, if you were to release your answer in draft, and then make an amendment, it will suit you much better as you will have created more content in the near term, and follow up with a much larger addition in the long term. This will allow you to both answer for the user wanting a quick response and answer for the future user wanting an in depth explanation.

Comment: `the intention to "no help", only "win"` How so, given that people who downvote don't benefit from doing so in any way?

Comment: @Pekka웃 That quote refers to people posting low quality fast answers, as opposed to taking the time to write a more detailed, higher quality, answer, but taking longer to do so.  It isn't about downvotes at all.

Comment: @Servy Indeed. -------

Answer (score 7):

If you see other people posting low quality answers to questions then use your vote to reflect that.  If someone is just copying a bit of code with no explanation, it usually results in a low quality answer.  Vote accordingly.  This is exactly why people have votes.

Comment: As I responded to you comment, the response is technically ok. The problem is that it is clear the intention to "no help", only "win"

Comment: Also, subjective questions are not off of topic at all. Is javascript a OOP is an opinionable question at all.

Comment: @angelcervera The answer you described is *not* "ok".  You described a low quality answer.  The intention of the author is irrelevant.  If they post a fantastic answer because they just want imaginary internet points, then great.  If the post really bad answers even though they just want to make the world a better place, that doesn't make the answer any less bad.  Evaluate posts based on their quality, not why the author posted them.

Comment: @angelcervera Questions that are primarily opinion based are off topic.  Questions can indeed incorporate a small amount of subjectivity, but if the answer is *primarily* opinion based, rather than objectively evaluable, then it's off topic.  Your example question would be primarily opinion based.

Comment: Maybe what you call "small amount of subjectivity" or "primarily opinion based", is for me subjective. :) Nobody is a god to decide that small difference but here there are people that think that he is. This is not the spirit of StackOverflow and this is the main reason because I'm starting to be worried. Nobody takes care of the attitude of people. It is a game, and all is valid. Anyway, it is my opinion, like this question. So be free to down vote. :)

Comment: @gnat found the right the duplicate. I am happy because other people it is feeling like me. I really thank you Servy for your response. It has been a good chat.